# Mount software raid HDD on Ubuntu

Tags: network-attached-storage

Have two HDDs should be using RAID1 (or RAID0) from a broken WD LiveDuo NAS device.

Put them on a Ubuntu machine, and try to get the data back. But cannot find a decent way to mount the drive, like mdadm etc. Anyone has similar experience to share? Thank you.

```
sdb         8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk  
├─sdb1      8:17   0   1.9G  0 part  
├─sdb2      8:18   0   1.9G  0 part  
├─sdb3      8:19   0   489M  0 part  
│ └─md2     9:2    0   489M  0 raid1 
└─sdb4      8:20   0   3.6T  0 part  
sdd         8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk  
├─sdd1      8:49   0   1.9G  0 part  
├─sdd2      8:50   0   1.9G  0 part  
├─sdd3      8:51   0   489M  0 part  
│ └─md2     9:2    0   489M  0 raid1 
└─sdd4      8:52   0   3.6T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0   3.6T  0 raid0
```

If using mdadm to check:

```
$sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb4
/dev/sdb4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 9f06b7e7:8bddca2f:8652963a:912c329f
           Name : MyBookLiveDuo:3
  Creation Time : Thu Jan  1 08:01:50 1970
     Raid Level : linear
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 7805003760 (3721.72 GiB 3996.16 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 0
   Super Offset : 7805003760 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 74277577:a7de248d:6dcb8539:777f5319

    Update Time : Thu Jan  1 08:01:50 1970
       Checksum : e25e5a25 - correct
         Events : 0

       Rounding : 0K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Another drive:

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdd4
/dev/sdd4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 55a7a293:527c2e26:53889c6f:27e89a10
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Sun Nov 22 21:45:29 2020
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 1

 Avail Dev Size : 7804739584 (3721.59 GiB 3996.03 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a1b70e73:4ec5a504:5bd31689:626d0227

    Update Time : Sun Nov 22 21:45:29 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 8 sectors
       Checksum : 3a643845 - correct
         Events : 0

     Chunk Size : 4K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Comment: screenshot at: https://imgur.com/ic06UDm

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the `md127` device. For example:

`mkdir /mnt/wd; mount /dev/md127 /mnt/wd`

If it does not work, please post the output of `blkid /dev/md127`

Comment: Thank you sir.    `blkid /dev/md127` output nothing.

Comment: `mount /dev/md127 /mnt/wd` failed with error message: 
**mount: /mnt/wd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md127, missing codepage or helper program, or other error**.

Comment: If using  `sudo mount /dev/sdd4 /mnt/wd`, got error message: 
**mount: /mnt/wd: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'**.

Comment: @M.L. if `blkid` does not show anything, it is possible that your RAID array is severely damaged and/or that some parts of it were zeroed.

Comment: Looks they were mounted?  `lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 十一 27 20:58 2 -> ../md2 
 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 十一 27 20:58 ubuntu:0 -> ../md127`

Comment: It's a RAID 0; you need all devices to mount it.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton. They were removed from WD NAS device directly, and didn't expect more devices to be there. It seems there is no way to get data back again?